# Firebase Error logging in with Google. 12501 null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

No clue why this is happening. keep getting this error

> Error logging in with Google. 12501 null

also this one.

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Code:

```
package com.workoutwager.workoutwager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.ResultCodes;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    //signed in
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginSuccess.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
                else{
                    //signed out

                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build()))
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // user is signed in!
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginSuccess.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Sign in canceled
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return;
        }

        // No network
        if (resultCode == ResultCodes.RESULT_NO_NETWORK) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // User is not signed in. Maybe just wait for the user to press
        // "sign in" again, or show a message.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.workoutwager.workoutwager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Where are you encountering this error? Is this randomly appearing in your logs? Or are there specific steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the module error... Have you checked the [prerequisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites)?

- A device running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or newer, and **Google Play services 10.0.0** or newer
- The Google Repository from the Android SDK Manager
- Android Studio 1.5 or higher

Try to update in `gradle` these and let's see if it works:

- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem in Firebase adding the SHA1 fingerprints in the Project Settings as it is required by Google login:

> To set up Google sign-in for your Android apps, you need to add the SHA1 fingerprint for each app on your Project Settings.

To get both the release and debug certificates follow the [Google APIs authentication guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Comment: The slightly different error message I got, which is solved by this answer, was "E/GoogleProvider: Error logging in with Google. 10 null".  A convenient way to get the SHA1 hash is to use the gradle task named "signingReport".

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue: 
`Error logging in with Google. 10 null`
and found out that i mistakenly had opted to use the google [play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing). The solution was then to copy the SHA-1 found in the google play console and enter this value into the firebase project settings.

Answer (score 0):

This statement [MUST go at the bottom](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) of your app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also, as mentioned in @anfuca's answer, it is important to use consistent versions of the Firebase libraries. In addition, use a compatible version of `firebase-ui-auth`, as listed in the table at the [Firebase UI page](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). Also note at that page that `firebase-ui-auth` has a transistive dependency on `firebase-auth`. You do not need to include `firebase-auth` in your dependencies.

My experience has been that the warning below is harmless.  I see it in my logs during and after succussful auth actions:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, check if you have added SHA1 fingerprints in your Firebase project settings.
- Second, Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials then **OAuth consent screen** and upload application logo.